# How to fix this calculate script for price, phone number, 2 digits and add textfield for cost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a calculate script for price, phone number and 2 digits from the last phone number.

Price will be displayed by select chained in my website. I have a little problem when price and 2 digits have automatic displayed. When price has automatic displayed and I input phone number, there is no automatic cost in cost column and still 0. I have to click in price column and digit column to display cost.

For example, if you input 2000 in price column and you input phone number, digit column will be automatic displayed, but there is no automatic cost in cost column and still 0. So, you have to click in price column and digit column to display cost.

And one a little problem again, if I add cost column with textfield like this code

```html
<tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td><input class="txt" onfocus="calculateSum()" name="sum" type="text" id="sum"></td>
</tr>
```

There is no also automatic cost in cost column with textfield.

How to display automatic cost in cost column and also with textfield? Are there solution about this script?

Example :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>berkelilingkesemua.info</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#phone_number').on('keyup', function() {
 $('#digits').val($(this).val().substr(-2));
});
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
 
    });
 
    function calculateSum() {
 
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
 
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
</script>
        
<table width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input class="txt" onfocus="calculateSum()" name="price" type="text" id="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td><input name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2 Digits</td>
        <td><input class="txt" onfocus="calculateSum()" name="digits" type="text" id="digits"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">Cost :</td>
        <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is unclear, please describe your problem without unnecessary introduction or greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear. I have tried to solve your problem as far as possible. Being new to web programming isn't a problem, but being unable to express your problem to others, may leave your question unanswered. So try to make your question as much simple and understandable as you can.

I have condensed your jQuery code to few lines, and made your two digits field readonly, so that it is calculated by code itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var price=$('#price'),
      phone=$('#phone_number'),
      digits=$('#digits'),
      sum=$('#sum');
  function calculateSum() {
    var digitsVal=parseInt(phone.val().substr(-2));
    digitsVal=isNaN(digitsVal)?0:digitsVal;
    digits.val(digitsVal);
    sum.html(parseFloat(price.val())+digitsVal);
  };
  phone.on('keyup', calculateSum);
  price.on('keyup', calculateSum);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>berkelilingkesemua.info</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input class="txt" name="price" type="text" id="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td><input name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2 Digits</td>
        <td><input class="txt" name="digits" type="text" id="digits" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">Cost :</td>
        <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Updates:
If you need to make cost a textfield and not span, then just make following changes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var price=$('#price'),
      phone=$('#phone_number'),
      digits=$('#digits'),
      sum=$('#sum');
  function calculateSum() {
    var digitsVal=parseInt(phone.val().substr(-2));
    digitsVal=isNaN(digitsVal)?0:digitsVal;
    digits.val(digitsVal);
    sum.val(parseFloat(price.val())+digitsVal);
  };
  phone.on('keyup', calculateSum);
  price.on('keyup', calculateSum);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>berkelilingkesemua.info</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input class="txt" name="price" type="text" id="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td><input name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2 Digits</td>
        <td><input class="txt" name="digits" type="text" id="digits" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">Cost :</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" value="0"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have made following changes:

```
sum.html(parseFloat(price.val())+digitsVal);
```

became

```
sum.val(parseFloat(price.val())+digitsVal);
```

and

```
<td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
```

became

```
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" value="0"></span></td>
```

Comment: I mean when I input the price and phone number, the cost will be automatic update from price and 2 digits, and also in textfiled like digit technique without button or press.

Comment: Your script what I mean, but not working in cost textfield and code `<span id="sum">0</span>`

Comment: Do you mean you need cost as a textfield rather than a span?

Comment: Yes, I mean need cost as a textfield and a span.

Comment: Updated the answer as you required. Have a look.

Comment: Ok, your script is working, but why there is "NaN" in cost box ?.

Comment: Ok, I have made following changes: `digitsVal=isNaN(digitsVal)?0:digitsVal;` became `var digitsVal=isNaN(digitsVal)?0:digitsVal;` and script is good. Thank you.

Comment: Yesterday, I had made following changes code `digitsVal=isNaN(digitsVal)?0:digitsVal;` became `var digitsVal=isNaN(digitsVal)?0:digitsVal;`. First the code was working, but second I tried to empty in cost box, there is still "NaN" in cost box. So I ask again in new thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650979/how-to-fix-this-calculate-script-which-has-nan-in-cost-box